# FCM push notification issue with Android Oreo

Tags: android, firebase, android-8.0-oreo

I've made an app with Xamarin (ios and Android).

I set up push notifications using Firebase FCM.
All is OK on iphone and Android version < 8 (notification well recieved when app is in foreground and notification are displayed when app is in background)

On my Android Oreo device, I have an issue. When app is in background, when I send push notification with postman, The notification is not displayed, BUT when I send a notification with the Firebase console, the notification is displayed !

I have created a channel on Android and set the android_channel_id in the json body, but it still doesn't work.

Do you have any idea on this issue ?

EDIT :

Postman (https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send) Raw code (one of the two ids is an iphone to ensure that notification is sent at each test) :

```
{
    "notification": {
  "body": "Test Body",
  "title": "Test Title",
  "priority": "high",
  "android_channel_id" : "first"
 },
"registration_ids": ["APA...g","fl...CS"]

}
```

The creation of the Notification Channel (Xamarin, Android part of code, in Main Activity OnCreate :

```
var chan1 = new NotificationChannel("first",
                    "first channel", NotificationImportance.High);
        chan1.LightColor = Color.Green;
        chan1.LockscreenVisibility = NotificationVisibility.Public;
        (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(NotificationService).CreateNotificationChannel(chan1);
```

Thank you,
   Luc.

Comment: Luc it would be helpful if you include some of your code to show how you have implemented FCM. And to know how you have implemented your own webservice to send messages--as well as what type of message your are sending using Postman (ie. Data only payload, Notification only payload or combination). And how you have set up your Notification Channel.

Comment: I have edited my question to insert the code. Thank you Barns

Comment: Thanks! Very helpful. :: Now I see you are using the `Legacy HTTP` post method instead of the newer `HTTP v1` API and you are sending a `Notification` only message (important to know, because Android handles `Data` and `Notification` messages types differently). Please have a look at this :: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive :: it explains that `Notification` messages received through the system tray when the app is in the background. This means the the `onMessageReceived()` method will not be triggered. Have a look if your code is not dependent on this behavior.

Comment: I've just read the firebase doc you gave me. The issue I have is that in App state "Background", my "Notification" does not appear in System tray as it is written when I send it with postman, but when I send a notification with firebase console, the notification appears in system tray !